# Using TableView with many custom Cells and autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, custom-cell

I want to refactor some Code for better Performance, but my Problem is i´m not sure how to do it. At the Moment i have one `UIViewController` with a `UIScrollView` on it.

I also have 20 different Views which (each has its on .h and .m File) can be laid fully dynamically on my `UIScrollView`. Every Time i start the `UIViewController` i send a request to my Server and then i get the Response and then i know how many Views i have to put on the `UIScrollView`. 
So you can imagine when theres a lot of different views on my `UIScrollView` it takes a few seconds because alle Views are getting fully loaded, before the User can finally interact with them.

So my idea is to replace the `UIScrollView` with a `UITableView` and change all the CustomViews (`UIViews`) to Custom `UITableViewCells`. So only the visible Cells would be loaded at the first start!

Know i have several Problems.

1. At the Moment, most of the Code from my CustomViews are build with `Frames`, but i want to change it completely to `Autolayout`, i don´t think it makes sense to build them all with the `IB` (xib files ...). So i have to do the whole Autolayout Stuff in Code?
2. Some of the Custom Views are really big, so they getting really high, and some can be really small. My concern is that the scrolling Perfomance will be really bad... because i cannot really use `estimatedRowHeight`(A Example: sometimes one Cell can get a height of 1000.0f and the next cell only 40.0f).And in Combination with Autolayout and the Time i have to wait until the Response frome my Server arrives, i think it could be really annoying for the User.
3. There can be up to 20 different!! custom rows, makes it really sense to use a `UITableView` in this case? As i mentioned before, they are all very different in their Size and Content!

Here is a little Part of my new Code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [self.node.blocks count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
GTBlockView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


GFBlock *block = [self.node.blocks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//createInterfaceforBlock -- Here the Cell gets called and the Content and the Size gets defined
cell = [[GTAppController sharedInstance]  createInterfaceForBlock:block];

// Make sure the constraints have been added to this cell, since it may have just been created from scratch
[cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];

return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

//GTBlockView is the SuperView of all my Custom Cells
GTBlockView *cell = [self.offscreenCells objectForKey:CellIdentifier];

if (!cell)
{
    cell = [[GTBlockView alloc] init];

    [self.offscreenCells setObject:cell forKey:CellIdentifier];
}

 GFBlock *block = [self.node.blocks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//createInterfaceforBlock -- Here the Cell gets called and the Content and the Size gets defined
cell = [[GTAppController sharedInstance] createInterfaceForBlock:block];

// Make sure the constraints have been added to this cell, since it may have just been created from scratch
[cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];


cell.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(cell.bounds));

[cell setNeedsLayout];
[cell layoutIfNeeded];

// Get the actual height required for the cell
CGFloat height = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;


height += 1;


return height;
}
```

Maybe some of you have some better Ideas or some good Sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done exactly as you are thinking in an app of my own - I first went down the UIScrollview route, then I changed to a UITableview with many kinds of custom cells.  It does make total sense and is very worth it - I gained a massive performance increase from the uitableview.  One of the major problems with the UIScrollview is that it will work out the autolayout for all the content in your contentView, which as you say, can take several seconds, but the UITableview will handle this much more quickly and efficiently.  So - go for it.

I would strongly suggest you use a unique XIB file for each custom cell.  Do the autolayout in each one individually, and that way you are much more likely to avoid problems down the line.  Programmatic constraints are far harder to maintain, and autolayout is often challenging.

To get it all working, I did the following : first I had a subclass of UITableviewCell that was the parent class for all the other cell objects.  In my case this was called SNFormTableCell (UITableviewCell).  Then all other cell objects were based on this class.  In my cellForRowAtIndexPath method, I do this :

```
ReportItem *objectForCell = [self.reportSet reportItemForSection:indexPath.section andRow:indexPath.row]; //my personal data class - just contains the cell data I need
NSString *identifier = [self getNibNameAndReusableIdentifierNameForObjectType:objectForCell.cellType.integerValue];
SNFormTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
if (!cell)
{
    [self registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:identifier bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:identifier];
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
[cell setSnFormTableCellDelegate:self];  //i have a delegate that calls back to the tableview when cells are interacted with
cell.reportItem = objectForCell; //put the data object onto the cell to do with as the cell requires
[cell refreshUI];  //update the UI using the data - this is over-ridden by the various subclasses of the cell
```

The method in there called `getNibNameAndReusableIdentifierNameForObjectType` .. looks like this (just gets the identifier we need for nib and re-use):

```
- (NSString*) getNibNameAndReusableIdentifierNameForObjectType:(SNFormTableObjectType)objectType {
if (objectType == SNFormTableObjectTypeBoolean) return @"SNBooleanCell";
if (objectType == SNFormTableObjectTypeDatePicker) return @"SNDatePickerCell";
if (objectType == SNFormTableObjectTypeDropDown) return @"SNDropDownCell";
if (objectType == SNFormTableObjectTypeDropDownPlusSingleLineText) return @"SNDropDownPlusSingleLineTextCell";
... etc
}
```

Then finally, the parent cell class has a method called -(void) refreshUI.  So I put the data object onto that cell - this contains all the data I might need for the cell. The the subclasses over-ride this refreshUI method in their own specific way, to use the data as they need to.

Just to re-iterate, I gained enormously from going down this route.  A scrollview with a lot of content, taking 5 or more seconds to load the nibs and calculate the autolayout (on the main thread too, making the app unresponsive), would appear instantly on the UITableview version.  So go for it.  If you need any more details on how to go about it, let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much! Sounds very good, the only thing i´m not sure about, if its a good idea to create such a lot of xib files...

Comment: Its fine really.  Way superior to doing it programmatically.  Ive done plenty of both and believe me, though it works fine programmatically you need to work it all out in your head.  Also and this is more important - in Interface Builder you can handle size classes properly - so you can change the constraints for ipad, iphone etc etc.  Really important.  Doing that programmatically doesnt bear thinking about!

Comment: Thank you very much, i will definitely give it a try, maybe you can show me what your "heightForRowAtIndexPath" look like?

Comment: Glad to help.  'heightForRowAtIndexPath' is no longer needed these days.  With the wonders of iOS8 and autolayout, they did away with that and now you just set your tableview to use 'automaticDimension', like this :     tableview.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

Comment: Yeah i know, but not when you have to support iOS 7 ;D

Comment: OK - do your very best to get out of supporting iOS7.  These performance increases you are going to get are much the better for use of the automaticDimension thing.  You will still get it quicker in iOS7 but Ive tried that too and its not as good.  Hey - iOS9 is nearly here, and uptake for iOS8 is already very high, so just dont support 7 (if you can!).